# Dynamically adding jQuery validation rules gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I've created a jQuery function to put on a `SELECT` element which creates a `change handler` that checks if the value of the `select` item  has a certain value and if so, display an element.
It also makes that element required for jQuery validation with this code:

```
fieldTextInputPlaceholder.find("input[type=text]").rules("add", {
                    required: true,
                    messages: {
                        required: "Subject is mandatory"
                    }
                });
```

The jQuery function is defined like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.dropdownlist = function (
            ......
            this.change(function () {
                doTheWork($('#' + event.target.id));
            });
            .....
            //doTheWork(this);
```

The good news is it works.

The bad news is that I want to execute the `onchange` code also on page load.

But when I do that I get this error:

**jqueryval:formatted:209 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined**

I've tried it on two ways:
`$('#SubjectDropDownValueId').trigger('change');`

Which is not a nice way I think

and also I've done it by directly running the code by uncommenting this line of code

`//doTheWork(this);`

On both cases I get the same error in jQuery validation (This is minified jQuery Validation code) in this part:

```
 rules: function(t, i) {
            var r = this[0], e, s, f, u, o, h;
            if (t) {
                e = n.data(r.form, "validator").settings;
```

EDIT

I've deleted all code and only added the validator in the onload and this also gives the same error

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#CMSubject').rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "subject is mandatory"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined, means `n.data(r.form, "validator")` is undefined, check if `r` and `r.form` is defined also check if `n` is defined.

Comment: This is minified jQuery Validation code...

Comment: It seems that `$(document).ready(function () { (function ($) { ...` is a DOM ready handler inside of a DOM ready handler.   See:  https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: **Where** is your call to the `.validate()` method and the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: the call to the validate method is done automaticly by the bootstrapping of the Razor view. I'll check if the double handler makes a difference if I remove one

Comment: If the call to `.validate()` is being done automatically by ASP, then don't you think that would have been good to mention *someplace* in your question?  Secondly, since we now finally know you're using ASP, that error is sometimes caused by an incorrect version of the jQuery Validate plugin and/or the unobtrusive validation plugin.